# In Blender 3.3, Object > Shade Smooth turns off Autosmooth. Why and how to disable this unwanted behavior?

Tags: smooth

Also, they added Shade AutoSmooth... which defaults to a sharpness angle of 30 degrees. So if you manually set the angle to, say, 90, then went Object > Shade Autosmooth, its reverts it to 30 degrees. Why the Blender devs thought this was a good behavior to add, I have no idea.

Comment: There would be no point in having both menu options in that case so it seems quite logical to me.   The first time you select Shade Autosmooth you can set the angle to whatever you want in the bottom-left property panel and it will then stay the same for any further use until you close Blender or start an new project. In any case there are no developers here so you should complain about it elsewhere.

Comment: @JohnEason and Buzzkill.  This, IMO, is a worthy Right-Click-Select suggestion. The threshold angle should be sticky, _per object_. The number is there, greyed out.. it shouldn't  be that hard to recover.